# How to evaluate this contour integral with branches?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts

I want to evaluate this integral below using contour integral. 
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+x^2)}$$
I know this can be done transforming x to sin or cos, but I want to solve this by techniques of complex analysis.

I tried key hole contour. I understand that the residues at 1 and -1 can’t be calculated as usual. Therefore I excluded those branch points by key hole contour. There are two small circles whose centers are 1 and -1, and two way path connects them. Using the property of branch, twice of the desired integral can be gained from the two way path. In order to exclude 1 and -1, I added one large circle which surrounds all of them.

In the contour, there are residues of i and -i, but the sum is equal to 0. Because integrals relates to circles vanishes under proper limit, this results in the desired integral is equal to 0, which is not the answer.

What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: Bounds are 1 to 1?  Should it be -1 to 1?

Comment: Sorry, -1 to 1 is right. I corrected.

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Usually contour integrals are for integrals that are over an infinite (or semi-infinite) domain. It seems like the trigonometric substitutions work best here

Comment: Thanks for your updated post. What are the explicit branch cuts you’re using? (Specify your range of argument for each of z-1 and z+1). Without knowing this, it’s hard to pin down what went wrong. It is possible that your two line integrals along -1 to 1 cancelled out, or you might have used the incorrect branch(es) when you evaluated the residues at +/- i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider a contour integral as in fig
\begin{gather}
\oint \frac{dz}{g(z)(1+z^2)}=\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{g(x+i0)(1+x^2)}-\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{g(x-i0)(1+x^2)},\ \ \ g(z)=\sqrt{1-z^2}.
\end{gather}
Now you fixate a regular branch of your multivalued $g(z)$ as
\begin{gather}
   g(x+i0)>0,\ \ x\in(-1,1)\ \ {\rm fixation\ of\ a\ regular\ branch}
\end{gather}
That means that $g(x-i0)=-g(x+i0)$ and also, that means that your original integral $I$ is equal to the integral along the upper bank of the contour. This way:
\begin{gather}
   \oint=2I.
\end{gather}
On the other hand:

\begin{gather}
   \oint=2\pi i\Big(\underset{z=i}{\rm res}\frac{1}{(1+z^2)g(z)}+\underset{z=-i}{\rm res}\frac{1}{(1+z^2)g(z)}\Big)=2\pi i\Big(\frac{1}{2i g(i)}+\frac{1}{-2i g(-i)}\Big).
\end{gather}
Now from the definition of your regular branch $g(i)=\sqrt{2}$ and $g(-i)=-\sqrt{2}$. Then:
\begin{gather}
   I=\frac{1}{2}\oint=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{gather}

[image]

Comment: Thank you! 
I have a question. Why do the residues at i and -i relate to this integral even though they are not inside of the contour?

Comment: @JpK because there should be a large circular contour (with radius tending to infinity). These two contours together enclose the poles at i and -i. Note that the integral along this large contour tends to zero, so all the contribution comes from the inside integral (the red one drawn by the answerer.

Comment: @stokes-line nice graph. How did you draw the figure? I’m interested in producing these figures.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: We have a whole online course dedicated to this subject. Its completely free, check our channel:  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcOPzqeuB8GTt1zfh6JKbSA/playlists

Comment: I think there are a couple of typos. The value of $g(-i)$ and the final equation seem off to me.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you! Corrected.

Comment: ok! And in the last equation, $I = \frac{1}{2} \oint = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Benjamin, I use adobe illustrator. But I've heard that inkscape is just as poweful.